# Should I use who or which? "a nurse is someone who/which always helps sick people."

Tags: relative-pronouns

Is it "a nurse is someone **who** always helps sick people." or " a nurse is someone **which** always helps sick people."?

Comment: "That" will work (as will "who"), but not "which".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the pronoun 'who' about people (and sometimes pet animals), and 'which' with animals and inanimate objects ('things').

> A nurse is a person **who** helps sick people.
>
> A stick is a piece of wood **which** is long and thin.

[Relative pronouns (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns)

Comment: I do wish that dictionaries like the Cambridge would refrain from calling relative "that" a pronoun, when in fact it's a subordinator (subordinate conjunction).

Comment: thank you Michael!